# How to fetch appid and password in AZ Cli PowerShell using jmespath?

Tags: azure, powershell, jmespath

Hello I am trying to create a service account using the below az cli commands. I am trying to fetch the appId and password into a powershell object using Jmespath. This is what I am trying to do.

```
$serviceprincipalname ="k8ssp"

$spdetails = $( az ad sp create-for-rbac `
--name $serviceprincipalname `
--query [appId, password])

write-output $spdetails
write-output $spdetails[0]
```

However the Jmespath query fails with the below error

az ad sp create-for-rbac: error: argument --query: invalid jmespath_type value: '[appId'

How can I select both the appId and password into a single object so that I can later split it and use it ?

Comment: `--query '[appid, password]'`?

Comment: That works... aaargh I just cannot believe I spent 30 minutes on that :-). However, this displays a null write-output $spdetails[0]

Comment: add '-o tsv' as the other answer suggest, however, i tend to output in json and parse it as an object, its better that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `--query "[appId, password]" -o tsv`

```
$result=(az ad sp create-for-rbac --name $serviceprincipalname --query "[appId, password]" -o tsv)
```

[image]